# How to get Course Id from Classroom URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, map-function, google-classroom

Goal: I want to quickly connect to a Google Classroom using a Google Classroom URL via Google Apps Script.

Problem: Need help filtering Map of courses by URL.

Background:
Classroom API has little documentation for GAS.  Furthermore, COURSE_ID is used for nearly all connections.  I can map the active courses, but I cannot filter the map. The code below originated from [Yagisanatode](https://yagisanatode.com/2020/05/13/google-apps-script-upload-grades-into-a-google-classroom-coursework-assignment/#Uploading_the_Grades_Only) with modifications in an attempt to map active courses by URL.  Changing the Logger to (courseData) reveals the creation of the double array.

```
function findCourseByUrl() {
const courseList = Classroom.Courses.list({"courseStates":["ACTIVE"]}).courses;


const courseData = courseList.map(course => {

    let ownerName = Classroom
                .Courses
                .Teachers
                .get(course.id, course.ownerId)
                .profile
                .name
                .fullName;


    return `[${course.name}, ${course.id}, ${ownerName}, ${course.alternateLink}]`;

});

const link = 'https://classroom.google.com/c/YOUCLASSROOMURL'; //change this
const data = courseData.filter(function(item){return item[4] === link;});
Logger.log(data);
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm stuck.

Comment: I am currently trying to work out how to create (using an app script) a url for a course.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
link is not defined since it is outside of the courseData.filter(function(item){}). The solution is to call a global variable or create a conditional with the declared variable within the function(item).

The toString is looking for an exact match for the URL text, which is naturally unique.
Video reference: https://youtu.be/PT_TDhMhWsE

Code:

```js
function findCourseByUrl() {
    const courseList = Classroom.Courses.list({"courseStates":["ACTIVE"]}).courses;
    
    
    const courseData = courseList.map(course => {
    
        let ownerName = Classroom
                    .Courses
                    .Teachers
                    .get(course.id, course.ownerId)
                    .profile
                    .name
                    .fullName;
              
 
        return `[${course.name}, ${course.id}, ${ownerName}, ${course.alternateLink}]`;
    
    });
    
    const filterCourse = function(item){
      let link = 'https://classroom.google.com/c/YOURCOURSEURL'  ///Change this or replace with a global variable
      if(item.toString().indexOf(link) === -1){
        return false;
      } else {
        return true
      }
    };

    
   let theCourse = courseData.filter(filterCourse);  //this could be a return if called by function in Test.gs
   
   Logger.log(theCourse); //remove if using a function with console.log in Test.gs

};
```

Comment: or in filterCourse `return !(item.toString().indexOf(link) === -1)`